# E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 100, last Errno: 2

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm implementing Foreign Keys in my SQLite DB in Android.

I had my DB working well without FK, but now, I have several problems.

One is when I try to get reference to db, I have this error.

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 100, last Errno: 2
```

My Function:

```
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
        // Opening new database
        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // Get Foreign Key Support
        mDatabase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");

    }
    return mDatabase;
}
```

The error happens in the line:

```
mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

It seems to be the first time that this line is called.
Other time, there is no pb.
I'm not sure it gives me direct errors, but I have several problems in SQLite, so it might contribute to bad behaviour.

Tx

Comment: Is there anyone to answer this? I have the same problem?

Comment: any one have solution ? facing same issues ,and doesn't find any solution yet ..

Comment: you got any solution @Juliatzin den Toro ?

Comment: @rathod bhavesh answer helped me, check if you have entered those permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: I really think Android would throw a different error if permissions really were the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is/was also your case. I just encountered this now and what I was trying to do was to download a sqlite zipped dump from my server and extracting it as my SQLite database. I used this [blog post as my guide](http://ingenious-camel.blogspot.com/2012/02/deploy-sqlite-database-on-android.html) (still works well in 2016).

I was getting the same error as you are, and when I downloaded the zip file to my laptop and tried to extract it (there were other posts saying that you'd encounter this error if your new database has change in structure and then you forgot to update your database version number) so I can get to the raw sql file, and I received an "Unable to expand ... Error 2" Error - meaning that the zip file is corrupt.

I am trying to get an updated version/backup of the zip file to test this theory but so far, all roads pointed to a corrupt zip file. I shall keep this posted.