# How to solve android sqlite errorcode 2

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a app which uses sqlite database for storing user data.  on trying to get writable database, I get following error in logcat.[image]

I searched for problem and found these links:

[E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 100, last Errno: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135397/e-sqlitelog-10-failed-to-do-file-read-got-0-amt-100-last-errno-2)

http://www.geekub.com/4367/0-amt-100-last-errno-2-e-sqlitelog-10-failed-to-do-file-read

But found no solution. 
There is no problem regarding permission or Context. 
However execution of query looks sucessful. Line just below sqlite log is printed by sqliteOpenHelper class on  creating table sucessfully.

How can I solve this?

```
  package classmanagement.management.college.com.classmanagementapp.model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by RaazDk on 12/20/2015.
 */
public class InAppCacheManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "class_management_db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String SPACE = " ";
    private static final String COMMA = ",";



    /**
     * Routine table and fields
     */
    private static final String TABLE_ROUTINE ="Tbl_routine";
    private static final String COL_SUBJECT_NAME = "col_sub";
    private static final String COL_TEACHER_NAME= "col_teacher";
    private static final String COL_START_TIME = "col_start_time";
    private static final String COL_END_TIME = "col_end_time";
    private static final String COL_DAY_INDEX ="col_day_index";
    /**
     * Comments table and fields
     */
    private static final String TABLE_COMMNETS = "Tbl_comments";
    private static final String COL_COMMENTS= "col_commnets";
    private static final String COL_COMMENTOR_REF ="col_commentor";

    /**
     *
     * Friend table and fields
     */
    private static final String TABLE_FRIENDS = "Tbl_Friends";
    private static final String COL_FRIEND_NAME = "col_friend_name";
    private static final String COL_FRIEND_ID = "col_id";
    private static final String COL_GROUP_NAME = "col_grp_name";
    private static final String COL_CLASS_NAME = "col_class_name";
    private static final String COL_SEMESTER_NAME = "col_semester_name";
    private static final String COL_E_MAIL = "col_friend_email";

    /**
     *
     * College Event table and fields
     *
     * @param context
     */

    private static  final String TABLE_EVENTS = "tbl_events";
    private static final String COL_EVENT_ID = "col_event_id";
    private static final String COL_EVENT_TITLE = "col_event_title";

    /**
     * Record Version table and Fields
     */

    private static final String TABLE_RECORD_VERSION = "tbl_rec_version";
    private static  final String COL_LAST_FRIEND_ID = "col_last_friend_id";
    private static final String COL_LAST_EVENT_ID ="col_last_event_id";
    private static final String COL_LAST_ROUTINE_ID = "col_last_routine_version";
    private static final String COL_LAST_HOLIDAY_ID = "col_last_holiday_version";


    /**
     *
     *Holiday table and Fields
     */

    private static final String TABLE_HOLIDAY = "tbl_holiday";
    private static final String COL_HOLIDAY_TITLE = "col_holiday_title";
    private static final String COL_HOLIDAY_DESC = "col_holiday_desc";
    private static final String COL_HOLIDAY_START = "col_holiday_start";
    private static final String COL_HOLIDAY_END = "col_holiday_end";


    /**
     * Queries to create tables.
     */

    private static final String CREATE_FRIENDS_TABLE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+SPACE+TABLE_FRIENDS
            +"("+COL_FRIEND_ID+SPACE+"INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY"+COMMA
                +COL_FRIEND_NAME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(300)"+COMMA+COL_E_MAIL+SPACE+"VARCHAR(100)"+COMMA+COL_CLASS_NAME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(50)"+COMMA
                +COL_SEMESTER_NAME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(50)"+COMMA+COL_GROUP_NAME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(50)"
            +")";

    private static final String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+SPACE+TABLE_EVENTS
            +"("+COL_EVENT_ID+SPACE+"INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY"+COMMA+COL_EVENT_TITLE+SPACE+"VARCHAR(200)"

            +")";
    private  static final String CREATE_HOLIDAY_TABLE_QUERY=" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+SPACE+TABLE_HOLIDAY
            +"(" +COL_HOLIDAY_TITLE+SPACE+"VARHCAR(200)"+COMMA+COL_HOLIDAY_DESC+SPACE+"VARCHAR(200)"+COMMA
                +COL_HOLIDAY_START+SPACE+"VARCHAR(200)"+COMMA+COL_HOLIDAY_END+SPACE+"VARCHAR(200)"
            + ")";
    private static final String CREATE_CLASSROUTINE_TABLE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+SPACE+TABLE_ROUTINE
            +"(" + COL_START_TIME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(20)"+COMMA+COL_END_TIME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(20)"+COMMA+COL_SUBJECT_NAME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(20)"
                 +COMMA+COL_TEACHER_NAME+SPACE+"VARCHAR(150)"
            +")";

    private static final String CREATE_REC_VERSION_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+SPACE+TABLE_RECORD_VERSION+
            "(" +COL_LAST_EVENT_ID+SPACE+"INTEGER NOT NULL"+COMMA+COL_LAST_FRIEND_ID+SPACE+"INTEGER NOT NULL"+COMMA
            +COL_LAST_HOLIDAY_ID+"INTEGER NOT NULL"+COMMA+COL_LAST_ROUTINE_ID+SPACE+"INTEGER NOT NULL"
            + ")";





    public InAppCacheManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {



        try {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_REC_VERSION_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_FRIENDS_TABLE_QUERY);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CLASSROUTINE_TABLE_QUERY);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_HOLIDAY_TABLE_QUERY);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE_QUERY);
            Log.i("Caching", "Caching environment all set");
           // Toast.makeText(mContext,"environemnt set for in-app caching",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (SQLException ex) {

            Log.e("CachingError;=>",ex.toString());
           // Toast.makeText(mContext,"Error in creating database for caching",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public class MapRoutine{

        String SubjectName;
        String TeacherName;
        String StartTime;
        String EndTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: And your code looks like what?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36092180/edit) to include your code

Comment: Also, you really should be accepting the answers to [your old questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4980199/raaz-dhakal)

Comment: @cricket_007 check the edit part.

Comment: I assume you correctly used the spaces and commas for all the fields? It is really difficult to read with all the capital letters

Comment: Ofcourse, there  are no syntax error, no exception while executing queries, yet I am getting this error code while trying to get writeable database.

Comment: I see you have not implemented `onUpgrade`. This error occurs when you [change the fields in your tables without upgrading your database](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/366).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/366), that error occurs when you modify the database without upgrading the database version.

Try implementing onUpgrade like so instead of having it be empty.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_1);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_2);
        // ...
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not solving the problem, I get this error on first time installation  of app .